# Iterate in a list of dictionaries and assign incremented values from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists which has values, I want to map the list2 value to list1 by referring to the 'cat' key. I want to iterate in list1, and if the 'cat' value of list1 is same as the previous 'cat' value, then it has to increment the list2 value and assign it into list1. If the value is different than the previous value, then the run breaks, and I want to go back to the first element of list2 and assign it.

Example:

```
list1 = [{'name':'aa','cat':'u1','Sno':1},
{'name':'bb','cat':'u1','Sno':2},
{'name':'bb','cat':'u1','Sno':3},
{'name':'ccc','cat':'u2','Sno':1},
{'name':'ccc','cat':'u2','Sno':2},
{'name':'cccc','cat':'u2','Sno':3},
{'name':'mmm','cat':'u3','Sno':1},
{'name':'nnn','cat':'u3','Sno':2},
{'name':'llll','cat':'u3','Sno':3}]
```

```
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
```

Output should be like this:

```
output = [{'name':'aa','cat':'u1','Sno':1,'seed':'a'},
{'name':'bb','cat':'u1','Sno':2,'seed':'b'},
{'name':'bb','cat':'u1','Sno':3,'seed':'c'},
{'name':'ccc','cat':'u2','Sno':1,'seed':'a'},
{'name':'ccc','cat':'u2','Sno':2,'seed':'b'},
{'name':'cccc','cat':'u2','Sno':3,'seed':'c'},
{'name':'mmm','cat':'u3','Sno':1,'seed':'a'},
{'name':'nnn','cat':'u3','Sno':2,'seed':'b'},
{'name':'llll','cat':'u3','Sno':3,'seed':'c'}]
```

thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried

Comment: from itertools import cycle;
lst = [{'name':'aa','cat':'u1','Sno':1},{'name':'bb','cat':'u1','Sno':2},{'name':'bb','cat':'u1','Sno':3},
{'name':'ccc','cat':'u2','Sno':1},{'name':'ccc','cat':'u2','Sno':2},{'name':'cccc','cat':'u2','Sno':3},{'name':'mmm','cat':'u3','Sno':1},{'name':'nnn','cat':'u3','Sno':2},{'name':'llll','cat':'u3','Sno':3}]
c = cycle(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']); 
for t in lst: 
    lst['seed'] = next(c)

print(c)

Comment: @Dev do not post long code in comments. You can write answer.

Comment: Why does your output's seed go a-b-c-a-b-c? Why do other values (e to h) not participate?

Comment: e to h not participating because i have only few input values so i need repeating the list2 values

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can ypu please explain how `{'name':'aa','cat':'u1','Sno':1,'seed':'a'}` and `{'name':'ccc','cat':'u2','Sno':1,'seed':'a'}` are created? Why are they both assigned `a`?

Comment: don't confuse I'll explain. I have two lists which has values I want to append the list2 values in list one values which has same 'cat' key values like if I have u1 value in 'cat' key i'll iterate the list two values seed name is 'a'  then next same 'cat' key values 'seed'  as 'b' if 'cat' key value is different from the previous one like 'u2' again the list2 values iterate initial stage like seed as 'a' that's i want.

Comment: What is Sno? Is it true that if Sno = 1 then assign a, if 2 then b, if 4 then c etc?

Comment: no don't consider Sno only consider 'cat' key. if cat key like u1 present in list then put a,b,c if cat key change again cycling the list2 values starts with a,b,c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on your clarification on your goal, this is actually pretty easy if you do an initialization and then simply iterate:

```
prev = ''
counter = 0
output = []

for e in list1:
    if e['cat'] == prev: # This is the increment step
        counter += 1
    else: # This is the reset step
        counter = 0
    e['seed'] = list2[counter]
    output.append(e)
    prev = e['cat']

# output:
[{'Sno': 1, 'cat': 'u1', 'name': 'aa', 'seed': 'a'},
 {'Sno': 2, 'cat': 'u1', 'name': 'bb', 'seed': 'b'},
 {'Sno': 3, 'cat': 'u1', 'name': 'bb', 'seed': 'c'},
 {'Sno': 1, 'cat': 'u2', 'name': 'ccc', 'seed': 'a'},
 {'Sno': 2, 'cat': 'u2', 'name': 'ccc', 'seed': 'b'},
 {'Sno': 3, 'cat': 'u2', 'name': 'cccc', 'seed': 'c'},
 {'Sno': 1, 'cat': 'u3', 'name': 'mmm', 'seed': 'a'},
 {'Sno': 2, 'cat': 'u3', 'name': 'nnn', 'seed': 'b'},
 {'Sno': 3, 'cat': 'u3', 'name': 'llll', 'seed': 'c'}]
```

What matters really is the `counter` getting either incremented by 1 or reset to zero. Then you just assign the corresponding element to your collection. I am sure there must be an itertools method as well, but this should solve the issue with base Python.